# How can I make a function that checks for duplicates return false if the input is null?

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to check for a duplicate:

```
        var duplicate = _.some(this.home.modal.data.subTopics, function (subTopic) {
            return subtopic.subTopicId === this.home.modal.subTopicId;
        });
```

It checks the `subTopicId` of each row in `home.modal.data.subTopics` to see if any match the value of this.home.modal.subTopicId.

However I have a problem if `this.home.modal.subTopicId` is null and it gives an error.

How can I change it so that it would never show a duplicate if this.home.modal.subTopicId was null? Ideally I would like to change it in the return area of the code but I am not sure how I could do this.

Comment: Eh.. you're not using the function argument `subTopic` inside your function...?

Comment: Samantha: If you're saying that one of the objects in `this.home.modal` may be `null`, then you'll need to test each one, or at least the ones that you know could be `null`.

Comment: @thebjorn - thanks. Seems that was also an error. Just corrected that.  Now I still have to change the return to do the check. I was thinking can I make that return return false if this.home.modal.subTopicId is null.

Comment: `return ... && this.home.modal.subTopicId !== null` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something as simple as:

```
var current = this.home.modal.subTopicId;
var duplicate = current && _.some(this.home.modal.data.subTopics, function (subTopicId) {
    return subTopicId === current;  // can't use outer `this` here..
});
```